# Does a drug charge preclude you from entering the UK?

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas

I was arrested and charged with possession of marijuana and cocaine in 2015. I never had a trial as I left the country before then. My question is: *assuming all other factors are acceptable (e.g. finances, sponsorship), does my outstanding arrest stop me from being granted a standard UK visitor's visa?*

I do not plan on lying in my application, but I also want to highlight that I never had a conviction, nor have I been in trouble since (I recently traveled through 4 countries, all in SE Asia where the visa requirements are much lower). *Am I being untrustworthy and therefore at even greater risk for being denied a visa?* For your reference I hold an American green card but I am not a national of any country that can visit the UK visa-free.

Comment: A pending trial can be a problem.

Comment: A charge isn't necessarily dropped if you leave the country, and a failure to appear may mean there is an outstanding warrant for your arrest. If it was the US, do you know whether your Green Card status hasn't been affected?

Comment: The UK standard visitor visa application asks: *Have you ever been charged in any country with a criminal offence for which you have not yet been tried in court (including traffic offences)?”*  Should you answer no, and be found out, you would be refused for deception, not a good thing on an immigration record.

Comment: `I never had a trial as I left the country before then` Basically you are a fugitive from justice. What makes you think you will get a UK visa when you disclose these facts. The chances are close to zero in my opinion. Secondly if your arrest and charge was in the USA, make sure you take care of that. You may have more important problems to worry about than just getting a UK visa.

Comment: In what country were you charged? UK? USA? Uzbekistan?

Comment: @Honorary World Citizen In reality, if he doesn't disclose the pending trial, they will never find out. A drug trial is not something they will put the OP on an Interpol watchlist.

Comment: @greatone the operative word in my comment was **disclose**.

Comment: Were you arrested _in the UK_? You might obtain a visa, and then be taken into custody at the airport on arrival.

Comment: @Honorary World Citizen I was arrested in the US. If I don't disclose my arrest, however, just as Giorgio states I will be lying on my application and I don't want to do that. What can I do?

Comment: There’s nothing you can do. Lie and get the visa, or tell the truth and get denied. The choice is yours. Make the choice that’s best for you and ignore the morality police.

Comment: @Honorary World Citizen I really appreciate your candor. Just to clarify, when you say lie and get the visa you mean if I lie I will have a better chance than telling the truth, yes? I don't think I'm guaranteed a visa, but without this issue my chances do seem much better. Does the UKBA do a serious background check for standard visas, if any?

Comment: @Michael Hampton Impossible. The OP probably doesn't even have a country-wide arrest warrant let alone an international one. The UK isn't going to arrest someone for a low-level crime in the USA. In theory, the OP would be liable to prosecution for lying but in reality the worst that will happen IF (a big IF) they find out is a refusal of entry and a subsequent ban.

Comment: @Kevin Sheng Don't listen to a bunch of strangers in the internet. Consult a solicitor. In practical terms though, you will not get a visa by telling the truth but you might by lying. The UKBA do backgrounds check but they probably don't have access to USA state-level arrest records. You should consult a US criminal lawyer to find out whether or not this was a federal crime. You should try and get the charges dropped. The UK does have access to some record in the USA on paper. In practical terms, it is more difficult to tell whether or not they do for this particular incident.

Comment: @greatone thanks for the advice. I believe these are federal crimes. It seems like it only matters if they find out it happened, and they won't take into consideration the circumstances (1st time non-violent, reform, etc) before and after the fact? Also, would you know the information of a solicitor I can contact? I'm lost as to where to start looking.

Comment: @Kevin Sheng extremely unlikely they will take those factors into account because the rules say "must put the application on hold." You should first try and contact a US based criminal lawyer in the state where this arrest happened. Perhaps you can try Google.

Comment: @KevinSheng  In my opinion unless you were involved in serious drug trafficking, the chances UK has or finds those records are slim. I personally would analyze this from a probability standpoint. In a simple non exhaustive analysis evaluating only the major outcomes these are the outcomes: you reveal and almost surely get the visa refused. Or do not reveal has two results, you get the visa or you do not (and get banned for ten years). For me it is an easy choice. Bill Clinton, Obama, George Bush all smoked weed or snorted cocaine by their own admission. I judge no man.

Comment: @greatone I had no way to know that because the OP had not told us what country he was arrested in at the time I posted that comment. So I don't understand why your comment is directed at me.

Answer (score 10):

> If a person has a prosecution pending for an offence or series of offences, you must put the
>   application on hold pending the outcome of the criminal proceedings.
>   However, although you must stick to the principle of innocent until proven guilty, insufficient
>   evidence to bring a case to court does not prevent you refusing the application. This is
>   because the standard of proof is lower for a refusal under character and/or conduct grounds.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673998/GGFR-Section-1-v29.0-EXT.PDF

Comment: +1 Who down voted this answer? Maybe you need to expand on the answer a bit to make people happy.